# Converting CSV file with column seperator to JSON

Tags: php, json, csv

I have a CSV file (my_data.csv) that I want to convert to JSON object.
With column ";" it gives me wrong result, with comma "," it works fine.
But I don't want edit the csv file. And I don't want use str_replace because the csv file is huge and it will take longer.
How can I change my conversion function to generate the correct JSON format ?
Here is my CSV file:

```
"Timestamp";"Longitude";"Latitude";"Client";"Price"
"2015-08-01 05:10:13";10.714069;48.031952;"test1";17.2
"2015-08-01 05:10:13";10.714069;48.031952;"test2";17.2
"2015-08-01 05:10:13";10.714069;48.031952;"test3";17.2
"2015-08-01 05:10:13";10.714069;48.031952;"test4";17.2
```

This is my PHP code

```
$file="data/my_file.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$rows = explode("\n", trim($csv));
$data = array_slice($rows, 1);
$keys = array_fill(0, count($data),$rows[0] );
$json = array_map(function ($row, $key) {
    return array_combine(str_getcsv($key), str_getcsv($row));
}, $data, $keys);
$data=json_encode($json);
echo $data;
```

I get this :

```
    [{"Timestamp;\"Longitude\";\"Latitude\";\"Client\";\"Price\"":"2015-08-01 05:10:13;10.714069;48.031952;\"test1\";17.2"},
{"Timestamp;\"Longitude\";\"Latitude\";\"Client\";\"Price\"":"2015-08-01 05:10:13;10.714069;48.031952;\"test2\";17.2"},
{"Timestamp;\"Longitude\";\"Latitude\";\"Client\";\"Price\"":"2015-08-01 05:10:13;10.714069;48.031952;\"test3\";17.2"},
{"Timestamp;\"Longitude\";\"Latitude\";\"Client\";\"Price\"":"2015-08-01 05:10:13;10.714069;48.031952;\"test4\";17.2"}]
```

It should be this :

```
[{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test1","Price":"17.2"},
{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test2","Price":"17.2"},
{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test3","Price":"17.2"},
{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test4","Price":"17.2"}]
```

Comment: You are reading a .csv from a file, in which case you could probably remove some of the file reading/splitting boilerplate in your code with [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). Or even `SplFileObject()` which is a traversable file object that you can treat as a .csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
return array_combine(str_getcsv($key), str_getcsv($row));
```

to

```
return array_combine(str_getcsv($key, ';'), str_getcsv($row, ';'));
```

Because the default value of parameter `$delimiter` is ',':

> array str_getcsv ( string $input [, **string $delimiter = ","** [, string
>   $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\" ]]] )

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved my day :)

Comment: That's great! Please "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem so that other users can see that it's the correct answer ;-) - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

```
<?php
$csvString = file_get_contents('/path/to/data.csv');
$csvRows = str_getcsv($csvString, "\n"); // split new lines, gives you rows
$rows = array();
foreach($csvRows as $row) {
    $rows[] = str_getcsv($row, ";"); // parse the rows
}

// remove the first row. its the CSV column heading line. keep keys for reuse.
$itemKeys = array_shift($rows);

// run over all rows and combine keys with values, to get a named array
foreach($rows as $rowKeys => $rowValues) {
    $array[] = array_combine($itemKeys, $rowValues);
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Result:

```
[{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test1","Price":"17.2"},
{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test2","Price":"17.2"},
{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test3","Price":"17.2"},
{"Timestamp":"2015-08-01 05:10:13","Longitude":"10.714069","Latitude":"48.031952","Client":"test4","Price":"17.2"}]
```